# Drop columns of Pandas DataFrame not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

I am using OneHotEncoder to impute categorical values and then removing the old columns with data type as 'object'

```
cv1 = (final_train.dtypes == 'object')
cols1 = list(cv1[cv1].index)

ohe = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = 'ignore', sparse=False)

oh_col_train = pd.DataFrame(ohe.fit_transform(final_train[cols1]))
oh_col_train.index = final_train.index

no_ohe_train = final_train.drop(cols1,axis=1)

print("Final : %d"%(len(final_train.columns)))
print("Cols1 : %d"%(len(cols1)))
print("oh_col_train : %d"%(len(oh_col_train.columns)))
print("no_ohe_train : %d"%(len(no_ohe_train.columns)))
```

The output is

```
Final : 80
Cols1 : 43
oh_col_train : 8295
no_ohe_train : 0
```

I am expecting "no_ohe_train.columns" to be size of 37 but it is 0.

Could someone point out the issue here.

Comment: Can't reproduce your bug with dummy data. Consider adding a sample of `final_train` (right before `no_ohe_train` is initialized). Also is there any code you're executing on `no_ohe_train` before printing the columns?

Comment: one raison that could lead to this behavior is that you have duplicated column's names. can you try `final_train.columns.nunique() == len(final_train.columns)`

Comment: consider adding column information

Comment: @not_speshal you can reproduce a similar behavior with `final_train = pd.DataFrame([[1,'a','2'], [2,'b','2']], columns=['a','a','b'])`

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the rest of the code it looks like cols1 list contains all of the final_train columns.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue.
Missed the detail that final_train had duplicate columns.